# Single Sign On (SSO) using JWT

Tags: cross-domain, single-sign-on, jwt

I have read several articles about sso but could not find an answer in my mind.
I have a scenario like below:

**Scenario:**

- My company wants to have sso mechanism using jwt.
- Company has 2 different domains like **abc.com** as **abc** and **xyz.com** as **xyz**.
- Also there is a **masterdomain** that manages clients authentication.
- User **X** wants to log in **abc** at first.
- **abc** sends credentials to **masterdomain** and **masterdomain** authenticates user then create a signed jwt in order to send back to **abc**.
- **abc** keeps this jwt in a cookie.
- After a while if a login to **abc** is attempted at the same computer, system does not ask for credentials and automatically login the user.

**Question:**

If user tries to open a page in **xyz** domain, how does the system understand that the user loggedin before? I mean **xyz** domain cannot reach the cookie of **abc** which has the jwt. What information should be sent to **xyz** that indicates the user **X** is trying to login?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can store the JWT authentication token in a cookie / localStorage of a intermediate domain connected to the home page using an iframe

[image: cross domain sso]

Scenario

> - **abc** sends credentials to **masterdomain** and **masterdomain** authenticates user then create a signed jwt in order to send back to abc.
> - <s>abc</s> **masterdomain** keeps this jwt in a cookie.
> - After a while if a login to **abc** is attempted at the same computer, system does not ask for credentials and automatically login the user.

Finally when the user enters in the second domain **xyz**, the jwt is recovered from **masterdomain** storage using the iframe, and automatically login the user

**CORS** is not a problem because **masterdomain.com** have access to its storage and communication between iframes is allowed if origin and destination are recognized (see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)

To simplify development, we have released recently an opensource project **cross domain SSO with JWT** at https://github.com/Aralink/ssojwt

Comment: what about the security if there is a phishing website which user entered and the user will lose the access token? does **ssojwt** corver this case?

Comment: @Vunb, iframe `postmessage` function requires that the origin and destination sites must be previously authorized, otherwise the browser will not allow the messaging, so an attacker can not access the shared token because it is not in the white list