# Azure API app with OAuth security does not accept accesToken

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-api-apps

First off, I am NOT using API Management. I just have an API dot net core app hosted in Azure. Now I want to secure the app with bearer tokens (OAuth). For some reason I can switch authentication/authorisation on and off, but when doing so, the call to the API redirects me to a login page in reflight from Chrome.

So my site is hosted at www.a.com and the API endpoint is served at www.b.com (azure hosted sites). Chrome is issueing a preflight to the api app and azure responds with a redirect.

My setup is actually quite simple and standard. I have a VueJS front end hosted as a static site, which uses azure AD for login. After successfull login, I want to call API hosted in azure as well. This API has to be secure. Somehow I cannot seem to get this fairly simple configuration to work.

I have registered the apps in azure, I have created scopes and gave the vuejs webclient admin consent for the scopes defined in the API app but I cannot seem to use the accesstoken from the webclient to call API's from the API app.

Is there someone out there for help?

Greets and thanks

John.

Comment: Actually my question is quite simple. I have a VueJS cdn hosted webite which calls an API app hosted in Azure (other domain). I want to expose a secure API. Because of CORS issues there is a preflight request. This actual request responds in a 302 redirect to a login page :-/  I already have a token, I want to continue to do the actual request with the accesstoken.....

Answer (score 0):

You can store the JWT authentication token in a cookie / localStorage of a intermediate domain connected to the home page using an iframe.

1.To authenticate the user in `example1.com`, redirect him to the authentication server in `sso.example.com`, issue a JWT after authenticating and store it in the localStorage of this domain. After this, redirect user to the origin domain `example1.com`.

2.Create an iframe in `example2.com` pointing to `sso.example.com`. The iframe in `sso.example.com` reads the JWT token and sends a message to the parent page

3.The parent page receives the message and gets the attached token continuing with the SSO flow.

To simplify development, we have released recently a cross domain SSO with JWT at https://github.com/Aralink/ssojwt

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527124/single-sign-on-sso-using-jwt?answertab=oldest#tab-top).